# Running jQuery animations in unison

Tags: jquery, hover, multiple-inheritance, target

I'm making a jQuery sliding menu, which activates on hover.

Looks awesome but I'm having to run the animation on two div elements side by side.

It seems to be working how I envisage it using the script below, but in IE 7 it does not, so I guess the script can be better.

The div elements that I'm running the animation on are bang tight up against each other, no gap in between.

So I thought, by using the script below, targeting the two divs which are next to each other.. **#sidebar-inner** and **#latest-tweet**, it would automatically stay on the first function, but when I roll from the **#sidebar-inner div** to the **#latest-tweet div**, in IE it runs the second function and then runs the first function.

```
    $('#sidebar-inner,#latest-tweet').hover(function() {
        $("#wrapper").animate({ left: "-178px" }, 300);
        $("#sidebar-slider").animate({ width: "512px" }, 300);
        $("#latest-tweet").animate({ width: "512px" }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $("#wrapper").animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
        $("#sidebar-slider").animate({ width: "334px" }, 300);
        $("#latest-tweet").animate({ width: "334px" }, 300);        
    });
```

How can I change the script so ultimately these will run in pure unison.

Or is it impossible?

Any help would be massively appreciated thank.

SEE SIMPLIFIED JSFIDDLE BASED ON QUESTION TO HELP THANKS
http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/9zeYc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your animations are queueing.  That is, they are getting added to one another.  Add `stop()` to your animations.  This will prevent them from continuing to run when they are hovered again:

```
$('#sidebar-inner, #latest-tweet').hover(function() {
    $("#sidebar-inner").stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);
    $("#latest-tweet").stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);
}, function() {
    $("#sidebar-inner").stop().animate({ right: "-250px" }, 300);
    $("#latest-tweet").stop().animate({ right: "-250px" }, 300);        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zc7LL/

You could also prevent the animations from queuing like this:

```
$("#sidebar-inner").animate({ right: "0" }, { duration: 300, queue: false });
```

However, this does not seem to be as smooth as stopping the animations.

Comment: seems good to me dude, another bit of jquery to the list, thanks for the explanations and taking a look at this. Awesome dude!